# Flutter Firestore plugin throws error when Archiving in Xcode

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-datastore, flutter, flutter-dependencies

After updating to the latest version of the `cloud_firestore` plugin (cf `pubspec.yaml` below), the application would no longer archive in the latest Xcode, although it runs on the emulator.

### Steps to Reproduce

1. run `flutter build ios` --> OK

   Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: xxxxxx

   Running pod install...                                      10,8s

   Running Xcode clean...                                       1,2s

   Starting Xcode build...
    ├─Building Dart code...                             23,5s
    ├─Assembling Flutter resources...                    2,1s
    └─Compiling, linking and signing...                 83,3s
   Xcode build done.
2. in Xcode, `Archive` ultimately fails :

### Logs

```
While building module 'ProtoRPC' imported from /Users/sergebesnard/Development/Noteworthy/RoByN/app/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/Protos/objc/google/firestore/v1beta1/Firestore.pbrpc.h:21:
While building module 'GRPCClient' imported from /Users/sergebesnard/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hizooagynttegaeqkhreoqwhrxzc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/gRPC-ProtoRPC/ProtoRPC.framework/Headers/ProtoRPC.h:20:
While building module 'RxLibrary' imported from /Users/sergebesnard/Development/Noteworthy/RoByN/app/ios/Pods/gRPC/src/objective-c/GRPCClient/GRPCCall.h:36:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
/Users/sergebesnard/Development/Noteworthy/RoByN/app/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/gRPC-RxLibrary/gRPC-RxLibrary-umbrella.h:23:9: error: include of non-modular header inside framework module 'RxLibrary': '/Users/sergebesnard/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hizooagynttegaeqkhreoqwhrxzc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/gRPC-RxLibrary/RxLibrary.framework/Headers/transformations/GRXMappingWriter.h' [-Werror,-Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module]
#import "transformations/GRXMappingWriter.h"
        ^
1 error generated.
While building module 'ProtoRPC' imported from /Users/sergebesnard/Development/Noteworthy/RoByN/app/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/Protos/objc/google/firestore/v1beta1/Firestore.pbrpc.h:21:
While building module 'GRPCClient' imported from /Users/sergebesnard/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hizooagynttegaeqkhreoqwhrxzc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/gRPC-ProtoRPC/ProtoRPC.framework/Headers/ProtoRPC.h:20:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Users/sergebesnard/Development/Noteworthy/RoByN/app/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/gRPC/gRPC-umbrella.h:13:
In file included from /Users/sergebesnard/Development/Noteworthy/RoByN/app/ios/Pods/gRPC/src/objective-c/GRPCClient/GRPCCall+ChannelArg.h:18:
/Users/sergebesnard/Development/Noteworthy/RoByN/app/ios/Pods/gRPC/src/objective-c/GRPCClient/GRPCCall.h:36:9: fatal error: could not build module 'RxLibrary'
#import <RxLibrary/GRXWriter.h>
 ~~~~~~~^
2 errors generated.
While building module 'ProtoRPC' imported from /Users/sergebesnard/Development/Noteworthy/RoByN/app/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/Protos/objc/google/firestore/v1beta1/Firestore.pbrpc.h:21:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Users/sergebesnard/Development/Noteworthy/RoByN/app/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/gRPC-ProtoRPC/gRPC-ProtoRPC-umbrella.h:14:
/Users/sergebesnard/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hizooagynttegaeqkhreoqwhrxzc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/gRPC-ProtoRPC/ProtoRPC.framework/Headers/ProtoRPC.h:20:9: fatal error: could not build module 'GRPCClient'
#import <GRPCClient/GRPCCall.h>
 ~~~~~~~^
3 errors generated.
In file included from /Users/sergebesnard/Development/Noteworthy/RoByN/app/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/Protos/objc/google/firestore/v1beta1/Firestore.pbrpc.m:17:
/Users/sergebesnard/Development/Noteworthy/RoByN/app/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/Protos/objc/google/firestore/v1beta1/Firestore.pbrpc.h:21:9: fatal error: could not build module 'ProtoRPC'
#import <ProtoRPC/ProtoService.h>
 ~~~~~~~^
4 errors generated.
```

flutter doctor -v
```

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.3.2, on Mac OS X 10.13.4 17E202, locale fr-BE)
    • Flutter version 0.3.2 at /Users/sergebesnard/Development/flutter
    • Framework revision 44b7e7d3f4 (4 weeks ago), 2018-04-20 01:02:44 -0700
    • Engine revision 09d05a3891
    • Dart version 2.0.0-dev.48.0.flutter-fe606f890b

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/sergebesnard/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-27, build-tools 27.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 9.3.1, Build version 9E501
    • ios-deploy 1.9.2
    • CocoaPods version 1.5.0

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 24.2.1
    • Dart plugin version 173.4700
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.23.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Dart Code extension version 2.12.1

[✓] Connected devices (1 available)
    • iPhone X • 780C4B10-21A6-41E0-9A05-A6175FC20FA0 • ios • iOS 11.3 (simulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Is probably related to [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16585)

Pubspec.yaml :

```
dependencies:


flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  google_sign_in: "^3.0.2"
  firebase_analytics: "^0.3.3"
  firebase_auth: "^0.5.10"
  firebase_database: "^0.4.6"
  firebase_storage: "^0.3.5"
  cloud_firestore: "^0.7.1"
```

Comment: switching to `channel master`didn't change anything

Comment: `flutter channel dev` same

Comment: Problem happens in gRPC-RxLibrary-umbrella.h :
#import "transformations/GRXMappingWriter.h"

Comment: tried `pod repo update` `sudo gem install cocoapods` `pode install` `pod update`

Comment: Is your app Swift-based? It works fine for me with an ObjC app fresh off `flutter create` and with the same dependencies you cite.

Comment: any solution for Swift yet?

Comment: The app is Obj-C based, but includes plugins written in Swift.

Comment: Swift being part of the mix is most likely all it takes. Have you tried the approach of the posted answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gRPC now fixed the issue where Archiving in xCode would crash. If you still have this issue today, it means your Pods are NOT updating correctly.

**Delete /ios/Podfile.lock and /ios/Pods**

That was how I finally got gRPC to load to latest version. gRPC needs to be 1.13 or higher to fix.

Comment: As of September 2018, this is probably a better solution than the accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: im deleting them and install - dont know work or not, +1 vote for help

Answer (score 5):

This works for me on an Objective-C based Flutter project with the cited dependencies, while I can reproduce with a Swift-based one.

The Swift error goes away, if I patch one of the pod umbrella header files:

`Pods/gRPC-RxLibrary/Support files/gRPC-RxLibrary-umbrella.h`

---following the advice of https://www.bountysource.com/issues/40110207-swift-could-not-build-modules-during-archiving-and-include-of-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module-rxlibrary.

Comment: Thanks Mikkel, it worked. I wonder how many more lines can be commented out like that in this jungle...

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and noticed that `flutter build` was setting a `BUILD_DIR` flag of `source root/build/ios` when building with `xcodebuild` (e.g. `xcodebuild BUILD_DIR=/Users/example/projects/flutter_app/build/ios ...`). I added this to my archiving command and it worked.

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, all of the deployment targets need to be the same. That is, in the project file, the target, and the pods' project as well.